# Is it possible to use DOS commands in my ANSI C programs?

Tags: c

i want to use the dos commands in my ansi-c program how can i do so what type of lib or .h i will need for it if it is possible ?

Comment: While zaharpopov answered your question, T.J. Crowder correctly points out that this is a bad idea. If you tell us why you want to do this, maybe we could help you solve your problem in a more portable and efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `system` function, from `stdlib.h`.

[Here is Wikipedia documentation of this function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_(C_standard_library))